# Find same sequence in two strings

Tags: python, sequence

I have two sets of hex data:

```
01 9b 09 45 00 00 b1 21 b1 2e 56 58 16 b9 bb 57 a1 cb 14 5f 66 33 fc 8e 22 6b 78 d9 d0 0f 06 e8 14 ee e5 66 57 75 f4 fe ca 23 5d 17 40 c7 f8 a7 f8 6b c9 e5 64 0c d7 1b 6e cf 76 31 50 03 6f 5b 14 78 90 bf d1 55 47 60 41 a8 f6 40 d6 59 ff 38 76 80 f9 83 db f8 a6 e5 d1 77 14 59 c7 d7 51 5c b9 0e 1a ed c2 d7 6b cf 9c f1 8a 64 d1 c9 73 30 9d 11 f7 b6 ff b3 99 b3 dc 34 00 16 5d 56 7d e6 80 6d d7 e6 aa 4c c2 2f b5 e7 97 16 21 9c 36 fa 98 3a d4 e4 e7 ce d7 b7 a9 b7 57 82 dc 4a 23 32 c8 b1 17 ac 0c 88 b2 c3 4d 52 52 e4 b1 25 6a 2d e9 a5 7d 19 32 c3 57 b9 59 35 c3 fa 85 01 52 62 61 7e 71 33 70 22 e1 e9 8b d9 73 77 8b 74 57 7a f6 a0 14 e8 2d 9b e2 26 ff 05 05 c0 fe 31 66 2e de ab ff 67 53 94 9e 33 23 8e d5 7e 99 7a f4 0a 26 58 56 50 19 91 88 6d 54 79 46 94 c0 ca 0b 19 b8 69 a2 d0 e5 dd 55 09 b9 5f c7 d8 20 fc 77 8e 69 21 93 85 2d 68 58 ff 04 0e c6 ce 2f d7 62 f1 08 48 c3 98 31 49 3d 2a 8e 0b 8a fb 3c e7 85 be de f9 dc 4e 01 cc ac af a3 87 a2 83 09 16 7b 7b 38 ba 7c 25 52 6b ad e0 10 f4 c9 de 19 d5 63 37 0c c7 64 56 3e f0 e2 39 74 e2 c1 0d e5 37 9c 18 a4 bb 72 d6 d3 7c 16 22 95 93 a8 ca 9c 61 ac 48 ad 0a 8b 26 ba 03 e8 2d 35 88 e4 95 fe c8 77 bf 59 65 d5 12 33 52 12 33 9e 69 ae 22 50 b9 39 ab 6f 00 27 ae 58 e7 ed d9 ac 9e 38 c9 ee bc a9 0d 4c 20 8f c1 ea 0d 21 97 12 10 3f bd 10 9a 9b b5 dc a3 83 9c d7 24 9e 3e 9b 52 6d 17 82 0e 32 8e 42 7c c5 ab 7b eb 4f 20 a3 03 a0 a2 33 d2 6e 68 24 a8 90 d8 ef ba b0 f6 82 0d 5f 14 81 de 1b c0 1f f4 9b 1b 7e 27 1d c6 05 cd 32 02 b7 09 4b 85 60 36 4c 63 60 1b 98 f8 8b 53 e5 78 60 bc d7 24 11 aa 0e f0 98 39 0a 57 ed 9d f4 b5 70 fe 88 20 f2 40 50 e7 9d 6f a0 a6 64 72 19 d5 ed 4c 35 0d 6b a6 74 a8 df b7 9c 01 56 0e ca 12 2e ca d0 12 7e 5d f6 2a 54 5e 0d 61 82 fe 99 8a 81 e3 56 a1 8f cf 4c d5 08 eb 50 d3 1a a4 de a3 fd 73 f8 9b ae 94 14 45 cd 0a 62 5c fb c3 86 7f 5d c8 95 42 7b a1 4b 19 59 71 1f 61 08 db 41 3a 71 ff 21 36 4c d4 4c 54 16 35 6d cd 92 15 14 3e 85 b9 02 69 d6 e5 ef 92 bb bb 98 23 d1 86 c6 10 13 b1 c4 82 3d 84 a7 9b 39 9a a7 51 b9 a1 39 56 e7 28 d6 a2 9e 00 2c cd a6 66 fa 5c bb 76 02 7c 5b f2 97 32 79 d4 fa 3b 82 ba 89 c6 9b b0 46 58 f6 a1 25 b2 d1 0a d6 84 c1 ab 01 00 a8 54 9d cb dc 80 f4 9d
```

And:

```
01 9b 09 45 00 00 4a 4e d2 73 90 d1 ff 21 37 6e dc b5 c8 97 ea 27 df 8d 37 a2 ff e1 c0 fc 6b 2d 53 63 1c a7 73 06 34 ff 1b b5 23 36 98 1e ca 4e bf 13 67 b5 ea f0 57 7f 06 73 57 12 8d 9a e0 27 63 75 7a 5e 82 9c bf 3b fd d0 57 2d 6e 0b 15 85 de fd f6 ee e6 34 77 59 29 5e 1d fe ab 22 ed 32 ec c6 2c 90 3c 50 7f 38 4c 4b f9 07 e0 81 bd 9a e4 46 60 24 32 ff cd 7c 42 ee 94 98 c2 74 10 5d b7 39 a9 6f 83 6e 6b 94 71 a9 33 e7 58 0d d7 9f fc 1f 01 3c 92 aa 0b 96 7f 21 a4 26 1b b7 00 e2 ed 7d 63 1c 7a 7d 1b 5b 11 71 40 3e 38 d1 e0 16 74 a8 07 3b 0e 99 e5 03 79 a2 60 e3 52 1d c5 c2 45 cb a1 10 20 d5 64 e1 de 4b d2 2f 0d 5c a9 89 9a f0 26 41 ec 63 61 e8 89 fc b8 05 c4 3c 3a 11 bc 9d 14 22 9b 43 82 c3 d5 bf d0 44 aa 2f 0e f5 9b 4c ae 5a e6 c4 1a da cd e6 d1 fc 10 60 a6 22 6d 4c 4d dd 19 19 6d 72 91 41 64 6b a8 b1 16 ec 99 17 3a 66 f0 b7 21 ba 83 ae 0e 62 f3 04 38 a1 79 5b 89 14 a3 25 2e 02 33 fd b3 98 d7 d0 3e 20 dc aa 09 32 87 b8 77 e4 24 1c 1c b9 f2 7a 2b c6 ce ae 0a 50 03 30 92 96 62 82 a3 b4 1a 0a 46 5e 18 79 1b 1b be d8 23 e9 20 53 79 12 fa 6b db ab 75 f4 48 45 79 b5 fe 93 70 d1 c8 c4 40 3c 77 10 e6 5f 1b cc d7 69 29 22 f3 ea ba bc 9f f0 3f da 72 a5 86 ac 67 f1 4a f6 be 9b 40 ee d0 e1 07 93 14 09 38 16 48 0c 60 80 4a 60 94 b6 64 f7 9c f3 71 50 c7 b8 75 a2 67 67 34 f5 8c fa 56 0c cc 73 37 ed b5 c9 86 e4 86 56 68 4c a3 01 b8 67 4c 90 8f e8 b6 1b 35 e4 06 31 7d 26 c5 7d bf 51 ec fc ef 82 dd b7 2b f9 1b cf e5 ad 87 7a 56 c4 43 90 f3 c1 25 a8 a7 38 87 aa dc 2d 4a 58 bf da 06 9f 6c 15 6a 70 c6 18 ad 3c d8 b6 23 e5 54 35 fd 4b 90 a7 44 de 84 4e 15 75 3b 85 1e ae 20 c5 13 f7 a6 4c 63 67 56 f1 16 48 82 4c 0d 47 f1 78 ca 59 ca 67 ee 1d be cb b9 fc 59 53 9f f0 50 21 31 4b 23 d2 02 7c 4a 7d 76 a9 05 b3 b0 5a d3 d2 08 54 42 18 b3 65 83 c9 2e 74 7e bc 03 f1 c0 f1 95 7e 68 a9 7c fc 07 b7 ba ff 7d 60 bd 7d b3 6b 0d 7e 40 4b b1 16 83 cb cd 33 1e b7 94 d0 d7 a3 ab 5e 29 66 f6 a7 91 09 f3 f1 a5 c1 78 b7 4f af 2a 55 1d cb b5 70 b0 68 44 2a fa fb e9 ff 62 0d ac 66 c7 4f 81 b8 4b ee 0c df d7 8e e1 b2 42 35 8a db 6b 04 5d 0d da 06 b1 3f da 74 cc e0 ec ca a7 e2 23 3a 14 ad 39 a9 14 20 d3 04 55 d6 eb db 0d d2 18 f8 02 ae 8b 45 c5 ef 69 82 7c 8e f7 10 71 b7
```

As you can see the first 6 bytes match in sequence:

```
01 9b 09 45 00 00
```

Using Python, how would I find all matching sequences in these two sets? It does not matter where it occurs, as long as they follow the same sequence in both files.

I would imagine I would loop through the first set and then find a matching charachter like 00 in the second one. If a match is found, then see if the next one is the same as the one in set 1. If so, look for the 3rd else skip, and try with the next char in loop.

```
for idx1, i in enumerate(set_1.split(" ")):
    for idx2, ii in enumerate(set_2.split(" ")):
        if i == ii:
            try:
                match = " ".join((i, set_1.split(" ")[idx1 + 1]))
                print match
            except:
                pass
```

How do you go deeper?

Comment: With more than 3krep, I'd expect you to know that SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: I would just like to know where to start, what this type of programming is called. Im guessing you loop through the set, and find the matching character like 00 and then see what the next is, if there is a match, look further, otherwise go to the next one

Comment: Wouldn't you vote to close this if it were someone else's?  The 3k rep gives you the privilege with the assumption that you know when to use it.

Comment: Looks like you already have an idea on how to do this: go get em tiger.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem and lots of possible duplicates (for Python alone): http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=longest+repeated+substring+%5Bpython%5D

Comment: I am looking for all common substrings

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "01 9b 09 45 00 00 b1 21 b1 2e 56 58 16 b9 bb 57 a1 cb 14 5f 66 33 fc 8e 22 6b 78 d9 d0 0f 06 e8 14 ee e5 66 57 75 f4 fe ca 23 5d 17 40 c7 f8 a7 f8 6b c9 e5 64 0c d7 1b 6e cf 76 31 50 03 6f 5b 14 78 90 bf d1 55 47 60 41 a8 f6 40 d6 59 ff 38 76 80 f9 83 db f8 a6 e5 d1 77 14 59 c7 d7 51 5c b9 0e 1a ed c2 d7 6b cf 9c f1 8a 64 d1 c9 73 30 9d 11 f7 b6 ff b3 99 b3 dc 34 00 16 5d 56 7d e6 80 6d d7 e6 aa 4c c2 2f b5 e7 97 16 21 9c 36 fa 98 3a d4 e4 e7 ce d7 b7 a9 b7 57 82 dc 4a 23 32 c8 b1 17 ac 0c 88 b2 c3 4d 52 52 e4 b1 25 6a 2d e9 a5 7d 19 32 c3 57 b9 59 35 c3 fa 85 01 52 62 61 7e 71 33 70 22 e1 e9 8b d9 73 77 8b 74 57 7a f6 a0 14 e8 2d 9b e2 26 ff 05 05 c0 fe 31 66 2e de ab ff 67 53 94 9e 33 23 8e d5 7e 99 7a f4 0a 26 58 56 50 19 91 88 6d 54 79 46 94 c0 ca 0b 19 b8 69 a2 d0 e5 dd 55 09 b9 5f c7 d8 20 fc 77 8e 69 21 93 85 2d 68 58 ff 04 0e c6 ce 2f d7 62 f1 08 48 c3 98 31 49 3d 2a 8e 0b 8a fb 3c e7 85 be de f9 dc 4e 01 cc ac af a3 87 a2 83 09 16 7b 7b 38 ba 7c 25 52 6b ad e0 10 f4 c9 de 19 d5 63 37 0c c7 64 56 3e f0 e2 39 74 e2 c1 0d e5 37 9c 18 a4 bb 72 d6 d3 7c 16 22 95 93 a8 ca 9c 61 ac 48 ad 0a 8b 26 ba 03 e8 2d 35 88 e4 95 fe c8 77 bf 59 65 d5 12 33 52 12 33 9e 69 ae 22 50 b9 39 ab 6f 00 27 ae 58 e7 ed d9 ac 9e 38 c9 ee bc a9 0d 4c 20 8f c1 ea 0d 21 97 12 10 3f bd 10 9a 9b b5 dc a3 83 9c d7 24 9e 3e 9b 52 6d 17 82 0e 32 8e 42 7c c5 ab 7b eb 4f 20 a3 03 a0 a2 33 d2 6e 68 24 a8 90 d8 ef ba b0 f6 82 0d 5f 14 81 de 1b c0 1f f4 9b 1b 7e 27 1d c6 05 cd 32 02 b7 09 4b 85 60 36 4c 63 60 1b 98 f8 8b 53 e5 78 60 bc d7 24 11 aa 0e f0 98 39 0a 57 ed 9d f4 b5 70 fe 88 20 f2 40 50 e7 9d 6f a0 a6 64 72 19 d5 ed 4c 35 0d 6b a6 74 a8 df b7 9c 01 56 0e ca 12 2e ca d0 12 7e 5d f6 2a 54 5e 0d 61 82 fe 99 8a 81 e3 56 a1 8f cf 4c d5 08 eb 50 d3 1a a4 de a3 fd 73 f8 9b ae 94 14 45 cd 0a 62 5c fb c3 86 7f 5d c8 95 42 7b a1 4b 19 59 71 1f 61 08 db 41 3a 71 ff 21 36 4c d4 4c 54 16 35 6d cd 92 15 14 3e 85 b9 02 69 d6 e5 ef 92 bb bb 98 23 d1 86 c6 10 13 b1 c4 82 3d 84 a7 9b 39 9a a7 51 b9 a1 39 56 e7 28 d6 a2 9e 00 2c cd a6 66 fa 5c bb 76 02 7c 5b f2 97 32 79 d4 fa 3b 82 ba 89 c6 9b b0 46 58 f6 a1 25 b2 d1 0a d6 84 c1 ab 01 00 a8 54 9d cb dc 80 f4 9d"
b = "01 9b 09 45 00 00 4a 4e d2 73 90 d1 ff 21 37 6e dc b5 c8 97 ea 27 df 8d 37 a2 ff e1 c0 fc 6b 2d 53 63 1c a7 73 06 34 ff 1b b5 23 36 98 1e ca 4e bf 13 67 b5 ea f0 57 7f 06 73 57 12 8d 9a e0 27 63 75 7a 5e 82 9c bf 3b fd d0 57 2d 6e 0b 15 85 de fd f6 ee e6 34 77 59 29 5e 1d fe ab 22 ed 32 ec c6 2c 90 3c 50 7f 38 4c 4b f9 07 e0 81 bd 9a e4 46 60 24 32 ff cd 7c 42 ee 94 98 c2 74 10 5d b7 39 a9 6f 83 6e 6b 94 71 a9 33 e7 58 0d d7 9f fc 1f 01 3c 92 aa 0b 96 7f 21 a4 26 1b b7 00 e2 ed 7d 63 1c 7a 7d 1b 5b 11 71 40 3e 38 d1 e0 16 74 a8 07 3b 0e 99 e5 03 79 a2 60 e3 52 1d c5 c2 45 cb a1 10 20 d5 64 e1 de 4b d2 2f 0d 5c a9 89 9a f0 26 41 ec 63 61 e8 89 fc b8 05 c4 3c 3a 11 bc 9d 14 22 9b 43 82 c3 d5 bf d0 44 aa 2f 0e f5 9b 4c ae 5a e6 c4 1a da cd e6 d1 fc 10 60 a6 22 6d 4c 4d dd 19 19 6d 72 91 41 64 6b a8 b1 16 ec 99 17 3a 66 f0 b7 21 ba 83 ae 0e 62 f3 04 38 a1 79 5b 89 14 a3 25 2e 02 33 fd b3 98 d7 d0 3e 20 dc aa 09 32 87 b8 77 e4 24 1c 1c b9 f2 7a 2b c6 ce ae 0a 50 03 30 92 96 62 82 a3 b4 1a 0a 46 5e 18 79 1b 1b be d8 23 e9 20 53 79 12 fa 6b db ab 75 f4 48 45 79 b5 fe 93 70 d1 c8 c4 40 3c 77 10 e6 5f 1b cc d7 69 29 22 f3 ea ba bc 9f f0 3f da 72 a5 86 ac 67 f1 4a f6 be 9b 40 ee d0 e1 07 93 14 09 38 16 48 0c 60 80 4a 60 94 b6 64 f7 9c f3 71 50 c7 b8 75 a2 67 67 34 f5 8c fa 56 0c cc 73 37 ed b5 c9 86 e4 86 56 68 4c a3 01 b8 67 4c 90 8f e8 b6 1b 35 e4 06 31 7d 26 c5 7d bf 51 ec fc ef 82 dd b7 2b f9 1b cf e5 ad 87 7a 56 c4 43 90 f3 c1 25 a8 a7 38 87 aa dc 2d 4a 58 bf da 06 9f 6c 15 6a 70 c6 18 ad 3c d8 b6 23 e5 54 35 fd 4b 90 a7 44 de 84 4e 15 75 3b 85 1e ae 20 c5 13 f7 a6 4c 63 67 56 f1 16 48 82 4c 0d 47 f1 78 ca 59 ca 67 ee 1d be cb b9 fc 59 53 9f f0 50 21 31 4b 23 d2 02 7c 4a 7d 76 a9 05 b3 b0 5a d3 d2 08 54 42 18 b3 65 83 c9 2e 74 7e bc 03 f1 c0 f1 95 7e 68 a9 7c fc 07 b7 ba ff 7d 60 bd 7d b3 6b 0d 7e 40 4b b1 16 83 cb cd 33 1e b7 94 d0 d7 a3 ab 5e 29 66 f6 a7 91 09 f3 f1 a5 c1 78 b7 4f af 2a 55 1d cb b5 70 b0 68 44 2a fa fb e9 ff 62 0d ac 66 c7 4f 81 b8 4b ee 0c df d7 8e e1 b2 42 35 8a db 6b 04 5d 0d da 06 b1 3f da 74 cc e0 ec ca a7 e2 23 3a 14 ad 39 a9 14 20 d3 04 55 d6 eb db 0d d2 18 f8 02 ae 8b 45 c5 ef 69 82 7c 8e f7 10 71 b7"

a = a.split(" ")
b = b.split(" ")
match = []

for x in range(len(a)):
  if a[x] == b[x]:
      match.append(a[x])

print(match)
```

As you said you just need to loop trought each set and compare each sequence and you see if they match together.

Comment: Great, much better than what i ended up doing! Thank you

Comment: mmm, it did find a sequance that did not exist when i search for it

Comment: I think its because it also considers it a match if only one char long, it should only consider two or longer

Comment: You find a sequence that did not exist with the two sets of hex data you gave ? Because it worked fine for me. Also he consider as match if two sequence are the same, and one sequence is delimited by space (since we split the sets by space) so it can be 1 char long or x char long

Comment: How would you do it for 3 strings? if c came allong

Comment: You just need to add to the if statement "and a[x] == c[x]"

Comment: And you also need to split c

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

def same_string(str1, str2):
   set1 = set(str1[begin:end] for (begin, end) in
              itertools.combinations(range(len(str1)+1), 2))
   set2 = set(str2[begin:end] for (begin, end) in
              itertools.combinations(range(len(str2)+1), 2))
   common = set1.intersection(set2)
   maximal = [com for com in common
              if sum((s.find(com) for s in common)) == -1 * (len(common)-1)]
   return [(s) for s in maximal]

same_string(string1,string2)
```

Comment: This is going into an infinite loop is seems to me

Answer (score 0):

Python standard library module `difflib` has a class `SequenceMatcher` which can be used to extract common substrings.
The first argument to the class is a function which takes one argument and returns boolean value. It is used to ignore chracters in the string. Second argument is the first string, third argument is the second string, fourth argument is a flag to toggle automatic junk detection.

**Output may differ if you switch strings**.

```
def common_substrings(is_junk=None, a='', b='', autojunk=True):
    matcher = SequenceMatcher(is_junk, a, b, autojunk)
    matches = matcher.get_matching_blocks()
    for match in matches:
        a_index, b_index, size = match
        if not size:
            break
        yield a[a_index:a_index+size]

print([' '.join(item) for item in common_substrings(None, hex1.split(), hex2.split(), False) if len(item) > 1])
```

Output;

```
['01 9b 09 45 00 00', '75 f4', '4c 63', 'b5 70']
```